# Angular 2Injecting Components at run time using Interfaces

Tags: angular

Been messing around in angular 2 and I'm trying to create a list component that can display multiple types of list items.

My approach was to create the various types of ListItemComponents separately and have them implement an IListItemComponent interface. Then I would specify what type of listItemComponent my listComponent will use through my parent component (homepage).

home.component.html (Parent)

```html
<h2>Home</h2>
 <infinite-scroll>Loading</infinite-scroll>
```

home.component.ts (Parent)

```js
import { Component, OnInit, provide, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {InfiniteScrollComponent} from '../../core/components/infinite_scroll/infinite_scroll.component';
import { ImageBoardService } from '../../core/services/test.image_board.service';
import { DataProviderToken } from '../../core/injection/data_provider.token';
import {ImageBoardItemComponent} from '../../core/components/image_board_item/image_board_item.component';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: '<home><home>',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    directives: [InfiniteScrollComponent],
    providers: [provide(DataProviderToken, {useClass: ImageBoardService})]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(InfiniteScrollComponent) private component: InfiniteScrollComponent;

    constructor() {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.component.setItemComponent(ImageBoardItemComponent);
    }
}
```

infinite_scroll_component.html (List)

```html
<div class="infinate_scroll">
    <div #container> 
            
    </div>
</div>
```

infinite_scroll_component.ts (List)

```js
import { Component, Compiler, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef,
        ComponentRef, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver} from '@angular/core';
import {IDataProvider} from '../../interfaces/data_provider.interface';
import { DataProviderToken } from '../../injection/data_provider.token';
import { IListItemComponent } from '../../interfaces/list_item_component.interface';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'infinite-scroll',
    templateUrl: 'infinite_scroll.component.html'
})
export class InfiniteScrollComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('placeholder', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef;
    private componentFactory: ComponentFactory<any>;

    private _dataProvider: IDataProvider;
    private _component: IListItemComponent;
    items: Array<any>;

    setItemComponent= function setItemComponent(component: IListItemComponent){
        this._component = component;
          this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory, 0);
    };

    constructor(@Inject(DataProviderToken) private dataProvider: IDataProvider,
                componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, compiler: Compiler) {
        this.componentFactory = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this._component);
        this._dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
       this.items = this._dataProvider.get();
    }
}
```

list_item_component.interface.ts (List Item Interface)

```js
export  interface IListItemComponent {

}
```

image_board_item.html (List Item)

```html
<div>
    <div>{{test}}</div>
</div>
```

image_board_item.component.ts (List Item)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IListItemComponent} from '../../interfaces/list_item_component.interface';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'image-board-item',
    templateUrl: 'image_board_item.html'
})
export class ImageBoardItemComponent implements IListItemComponent {
    test = 'test';
}
```

I am having trouble with the following line within 
[infinite_scroll_component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM7af.png)

Still not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. Can I pass a component from my homepage to my list component which accepts an interface rather than a component. Then Inject it at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

You may try below, Instead of Interface create a concrete class,

**ListItemComponent**

```
@Component({})
export  interface ListItemComponent {

}
```

and then extend the `ImageBoardItemComponent` class like below,

**ImageBoardItemComponent**

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'image-board-item',
  templateUrl: 'image_board_item.html'
})
export class ImageBoardItemComponent extends ListItemComponent {
   test = 'test';

   constructor(){
      super();
   }
}
```

create the component factory when you have actual component class may be in `setItemComponent` function.

Interface is not working because `resolveComponentFactory` takes an concrete class, you may read about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentFactoryResolver-class.html#!#resolveComponentFactory-anchor)